# Creating a 3x3 Matrix and multiply it with a Vector

Tags: c#, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I try to do some math with my C# project. I created a 3x3 Matrix like this:

```
double[,] matrix = new double[3, 3];
matrix[0, 0] = R11;
matrix[0, 1] = R12;
matrix[0, 2] = R13;
matrix[1, 0] = R21;
matrix[1, 1] = R22;
matrix[1, 2] = R23;
matrix[2, 0] = R31;
matrix[2, 1] = R32;
matrix[2, 2] = R33;
```

After that I want to multiply this 3x3 matrix with a vector I created, like this:

```
Vector3D PoiROT = Vector3D.Multiply(POI , RotMatrix);
```

POI is a Vector3D. But in this multiplication function, I got a compile error. 
argument "2": convertion from "double[,]" to "double" not possible. I also tried a different implementation.

```
Matrix3D matrix1 = new Matrix3D(R11, R12, R13, 0, R21, R22, R23, 0, R31, R32, R33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The multiplication works with this matrix. But I am not sure if the implementation is correct, to represent a 3x3 matrix. I am asking because my solution should be different.

Comment: `Matrix3D` is a class, not a 2D array. You should implement your own multiplication function if you want your custom matrix format to work.

Comment: If you just need a Linear algebra library us may checkout [Math.Net](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

Comment: The vector API doesn't have that multiply at all, but it has `Transform(Vector3, Quaternion)` and if you have a rotation matrix then you can use a quaternion instead. Is that OK with you?

Comment: Actually I don't really get what you're using here, is this with `System.Numerics.Vectors` or something else?

Comment: @harold probably [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.multiply?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: I created the rotation matrix with quaternions from my sensor. So i can use my quaternions with the Transform function? I just want to rotate my vector with the quaternions i got!

Comment: @WalterNazarenus yes but *do* use the built-in Quaternion class rather than another array...